# How to truncate text by using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I truncate text from N words by using CSS?

HTML:

```
<h5 style="font-size:14px"><span class="icon-home"></span>  B/1 Rajasthan Appartment, Kabirchowk, Sabarmati, Ahmedabad</h5>
```

I want to trunacate text after a kabirchowk how can I do this?

Comment: You can't really truncate a text after a specific word/char, but you can set the width of the `h5` element and have the `overflow: hidden` to make sure that everything that doesn't fit inside that width will not be displayed.

Comment: @Dekel still it not working

Comment: <h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;overflow-y: hidden;"><span class="icon-home"></span>  B/1 Rajasthan Appartment, Kabirchowk, Sabarmati, Ahmedabad</h5> I applied following code.

Comment: but if you have `width: 100%` it will take all width. you can set it to `width: 100px` (or some other value).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to truncate text in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150120/how-to-truncate-text-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

I found it. it worked for me.

```
 <h5 style="font-size:14px;width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;"><span class="icon-home"></span>  <?php echo $p["Address1"];?></h5>
```