# Trim the characters if the text is not fitting inside fixed width table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with fixed width table cell. The table cells can have strings with very lengthy characters. I know we can actually wrap the words or break the words with CSS properties. But I'm looking more into a solution where when the text length exceeds the table cell width, trim the word and add **...** infront of the word and show the complete text on hover of the cell.

```css
 td {
      border: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 120px;">
            Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
        </td>
        <td><span style="display: inline;">Short word</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Something like this

[image]

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: This is easily achievable by CSS. Why would you not want it? And you can put the entire text as tooltip

Comment: I'm even ok with the solution from CSS. I just mentioned that I dont want to break the word and wrop in the cell, rather want to trim the word and add ... in front of it

Comment: I have added an answer which adds tooltip and ellipsis effect only when the text goes beyond bounds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to truncate text in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150120/how-to-truncate-text-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily via css.  Try this:

```
.truncate {
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and then modify your td to include this class:

```
<td class="truncate">
Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
</td>
```

Thank you!
Shawn

Comment: Thanks.. This is exactly what I was looking. :)

Comment: Can u kindly tell me how can we achieve this same result using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the long text in a separate element, which is also restricted by width and then add the text styles.

I have also added hover styles, but if there is really such a long text, the experience of hovering and seeing the text cell expanding seems a bit strange.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.long-text {
  width:120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.long-text:hover{
  overflow:initial;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 120px;">
     <div class="long-text"> Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
     </div>
    </td>
    <td><span style="display: inline;">Short word</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```css
 td {
   border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  float: left;
    }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px;">
            Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
        </td>
        <td><span style="display: inline;">Short word</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little bit of JS to detect if the string crosses the `td`'s width. And use pseudo elements for ellipsis effect

You can call the following JS snippet at window resize or any other place if you want responsive text-ellipsis effect and add/remove tooltip.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('inner-text');

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  //check if inner text width greater than parent width
  if (els[i].offsetWidth > els[i].parentElement.offsetWidth) {
    //its a long text
    els[i].parentElement.classList.add('long-text');
    els[i].setAttribute('title', els[i].textContent);
  } else {
    //use this part if you want to remove tooltip or the class later on
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}

.long-text {
  position: relative;
}

.long-text:after {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 2px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 120px;">
      <div class="inner-text"> Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span style="display: inline;">Some random text</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 120px;">
      <div class="inner-text"> Short word
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span style="display: inline;">Some random text</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. I am not sure though, if using `offsetWidth` is the correct way here