# How can i display just 2 lines of my dynamic text in this area ending with 3 dots and then the 'read more' link next to it

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i have tried giving css(ellipsis) property. but it is trimming the first line itself.i need to show two lines (if i can set up max length character also is fine). I have gone through the 'limit' property in angular to trim text but it is not happening inside this InnerHTML content.
please see my HTML:

```
<div>
  <p class='ellipsis' [innerHTML]="news.newsText"></p>
  <a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="readmoreFunc(news)">Read more</a>
</div>
```

This is the result in UI by now.
[image: This is the result in UI by now...]

Comment: Have a look: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to truncate text in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150120/how-to-truncate-text-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

```
.ellipsis {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot....this  one solved my issue.THANKYOU @JithinAji

Comment: feels good to help :))) @RazanaRazak