# How to truncate long text to be into 1 line in bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, bootstrap-4

I want to truncate some long text into a single line in bootstrap 4, I have read many solutions here such as [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093908/ellipsis-to-truncate-a-long-text), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css), [Link 3](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) but they were not helpful.

The text I have:

[image]

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

But this happened with the code as shown below, the table line protrudes outwards a bit, and the text is not in a single line.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
     <div class="row">
            <div class="font-14">
                <table id="userLogTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">#</th>
                            <th class="text-center">LOG LIST</th>
                            <th class="text-center">DETAIL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    columns: [
        { data : "id", "className": "text-center" },
        { data : "log_info", "className": "text-log" },
        { data : "log_id", "className": "text-center",
            render: function(data) {
                return "...";     
            }
        }
    ],

.text-log {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1; /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet or code-pen please

Comment: Try adding `white-space: nowrap` in your css

Answer (score 2):

Fix the height of the row and make `overflow:scroll`. This must work.

```
ATTR{
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:15px;
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ATTR::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

ATTR {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: normally for make only 1 line, what is the exact height number?

Comment: what's the issue that you are facing with this solution

Comment: Take a look on this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll

Comment: I don't want use a scroll bar, as you can see I have put "notepad" icon at the right, that will show full log when clicked.

Comment: Then keep `overflow:hidden` and change the height to fit the text on click

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect just use

```
td.text-log {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1; /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use just these lines to truncate the text:

```css
.text-log {
    display: block; //in case if it is not block already 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```